# Symfony RedirectToRoute with array paramater

Tags: php, symfony

I'm working on an upload system based on Symfony 4 and PHPSpreadsheet.
My user uploads the excel file. I then create the products/categories... At the end I want to get all categories created. The following Doctrine query :

```php
/**
* @param $user_id
* @return array
* @throws \Doctrine\ORM\NonUniqueResultException
*/
public function checkIfNew($user_id): ?array {
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->andWhere('c.categorie_parent_id is NULL')
        ->andWhere('c.created_by = :val')
        ->setParameter('val', $user_id)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
        ;
}
```

gets all my categories where `created_by` is by the user ID, and where Parent is null.

What I want to do is to get an array of all those categories and then redirect the user to a rendered Twig template page where he can make the link.
But I don't really understand how to use the parameters...
In my Upload I've set this :

```php
$isNew = $this->getDoctrine()
       ->getRepository(Categorie::class)
       ->checkIfNew($this->getUser()->getId());
         if (!is_null($isNew)){
          $this->addFlash('success', 'Catalogue crée avec succès');
          return $this->redirectToRoute('admin.categorie.link', $this->getUser()->getId());
        }
```

I don't understand how I can use the request to redirect the user correctly using the route :

```php
/**
* @Route("/admin/categories/import", name="admin.categorie.link", methods={"GET|POST"})
* @param Categorie $categories
*/
public function linkImport()
{
    // What TODO here ?
    return $this->render('admin/categories/link.html.twig', compact('categories'));
}
```

Well I suppose I have to add `$isNew` as a parameter for my request ? But did I reuse the array after to use this in my twig, and display the element from this array inside my twig.

Comment: in your upload, just `return $this->redirectToRoute('admin.categorie.link');` and query the db again in your `linkImport()`? ... Theoretically, it should yield the same result. If that is not sufficient and you actually want to add the categories to your redirect, comment again ;o)

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. Well I was trying stuff and I duplicate this code but I forgot to remvove rhe request inside my return that's my fault sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a small error:

If your route is "/admin/categories/import" and you want to transfer a value like "$this->getUser()->getId()" then this should be like

Route "/admin/categories/import/{userId}" and your return would be:

```
return $this->redirectToRoute('admin.categorie.link', ['userId' => $this->getUser()->getId()]);
```

and your controller could take the userId as var:

```
/**
 * @Route("/admin/categories/import/{userId}", name="admin.categorie.link", methods={"GET|POST"})
 */
public function linkImport(int $userId, EntityManagerInterface $em) // var name must be the same as in the route
{
    // What TODO here ?
    $categories = $em->getRepository(Categories::class)->findByUserId($userId);

    return $this->render('admin/categories/link.html.twig', ['categories' => $categories]);
}
```

Now you can access your categories in twig with {{categories}}

Comment: Hi @DasBen  thanks for your answer, I've tried but I change a bit one line to reuse my my function `checkIfNew`, I Did this : ```php $categories = $this->em->getRepository(Categorie::class)->checkIfNew($userId);```, but I had an error : _Could not resolve argument $userId of "App\Controller\Admin\CategorieController::linkimport()", maybe you forgot to register the controller as a service or missed tagging it with the "controller.service_arguments"?_ . Do you know why ?

Comment: I don't see any reason to include the user id in the route/uri/function head. use `$this->getUser()->getId()` in your `checkIfNew(...)` call.

Comment: The edit on your route could be missing. I've edited my answer to include that part for linkImport